# Python issue when using line.replace() with space

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently working on a few lines where i want to replace symbol semicolon ";" with symbol "]". I am using line.replace(";","]"). Somehow i find that it is not working when the location of the semicolon is not consistent in a line.

Example:

```
input add_clk; #this one works where the output will be input add_clk]
```

However, it is not working for line below:

```
input sub_clk ; #tnothing change to the output, input sub_clk
```

The line that i used in my script is:

```
if ";" in line:
    line = line.replace(";","]")
```

Somehow i figured out that this problem may due to a space before the semicolon. Is there anyway the script can ignore the space so that the output will be input sub_clk] ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works on my terminal:

```
>>> a = "input sub_clk ;"
>>> if ";" in a:
...     a = a.replace(";", "]")
... 
>>> a
'input sub_clk ]'
>>>
```

Maybe there are some invisible characters in your string? At least, I cannot see any issue in your code.

If you want to replace semicolon and remove the spaces before it, you can try do it like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "input sub_clk ;"
>>> a = a.rstrip()
>>> a = re.sub("\\s*;$","]",a)
>>> a
'input sub_clk]'
```

Comment: Hi, i tried using your solution it works. Thanks alot !! You're right, maybe there are some invisible characters in my string.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is working fine in my PC. You can try this to remove spaces from your input:

```
l = input()
if ";" in l:
    l = l.replace(";","]").replace(" ","")
print(l)
```